# HTML5 canvas - fillStyle is not working for

Tags: html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to make a circular arc such that it has 2 lines and both the lines are joined together using 2 arc(connecting top and bottom of the lines respectively)

https://jsfiddle.net/AnuragSinha/94d5gy6u/1/

```
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    this.max = 100;
    this.min = 0;
    var start = 0;
    var end = 100;
    this.radius=100;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var startAngle = 3/8*2*Math.PI + ((3/4*2*Math.PI)/(this.max - this.min) * start);
    var endAngle = (3/8*2*Math.PI + ((3/4*2*Math.PI)/(this.max - this.min) * end));
    var r = this.radius;
    var x1 = r - (r-5)* Math.cos(Math.PI - startAngle);
    var y1 = r + (r-5)* Math.sin(Math.PI - startAngle);

    var x2 = r - (r - r/10)* Math.cos(Math.PI - startAngle);
    var y2 = r + (r - r/10)* Math.sin(Math.PI - startAngle);

    var x3 = r - (r-5)* Math.cos(Math.PI - endAngle+0.05);
    var y3 = r + (r-5)* Math.sin(Math.PI - endAngle+0.05);

    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

    ctx.arc(this.radius, this.radius, this.radius-(this.radius/10), startAngle, endAngle-0.05);
    ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);

    ctx.arc(this.radius, this.radius, this.radius-(5), endAngle-0.05, startAngle, true);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill;
    ctx.strokeStyle='#8ED6FF';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
```

Although the drawing has come up clean but I am not able to fill the color inside this shape. Found few other threads which talk about calling `beginPath()` and `closePath()` APIs but that didn't help too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove all the `lineTo` and `moveTo` calls and move the `closePath` to before the `stroke` and `fill` calls but after the last `arc()`

Comment: arghhh! turns out to be a typo. Notice that I am invoking ctx.fill instead of ctx.fill(). Once I change that it works well. Thanks @Blindman67 , indeed I don't need to call moveTo and lineTo here

Comment: @AnuragSinha. Glad you got it sorted. :-) Since your solution was just fixing a typo you might want to delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute the fill method

```
ctx.fill();
```